# auth.currentuser.uid becomes null after clearing app data and cache android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I'm having a problem with my app that it throw an error as shown below. Lastly, the app was working fine but when I cleared app data and cache It starts to crash if I intent to log in. the problem may relate with auth.currentuser.uid of firebase.I have tried to uninstall the app, restart the phone and reinstall the app but the problem still exist. please kindly help. thanks in advance!

the code and the error as shown below

```
class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
    private lateinit var binding: ActivitySignInBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivitySignInBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val view = binding.root
        setContentView(view)
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

        binding.btnLogInTutor.setOnClickListener{
            logInToSignUp()
        }
    }

    private fun logInToSignUp() {
        val uid = auth.currentUser!!.uid
        val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("$uid", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val user = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("LoginStatus", false)
        Log.i("check boolean", "$user")
        val email = binding.tvTutorUsername.text.toString()
        val password = binding.tvTutorPassword.text.toString()
        if (email.isEmpty()){
            binding.tvTutorUsername.error="ATC Username Empty"
            binding.tvTutorUsername.requestFocus()
        }else if (password.isEmpty())
        {
            binding.tvTutorPassword.error="Password Empty"
            binding.tvTutorPassword.requestFocus()
        }else if(!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()){
            binding.tvTutorUsername.error="Invalid UserName"
            binding.tvTutorUsername.requestFocus()
        } else{
            auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
                .addOnCompleteListener{ task ->
                    if (task.isSuccessful) {

                        if (user){

                            if (email.contains("tutor")) {
                                val intent = Intent(this, TeacherClassroomActivity::class.java)
                                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
                                intent.putExtra("email", email)
                                startActivity(intent)
                                finish()
                                Toast.makeText(this, "Login Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                            } else {
                                val intent = Intent(this, StudentClassroomActivity::class.java)
                                intent.putExtra("email", email)
                                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
                                startActivity(intent)
                                finish()
                                Toast.makeText(this, "Login Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                            }
                    }
                        else{
                                val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("$uid", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                                var editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
                                editor.putBoolean("LoginStatus", true).commit()
                                val intent = Intent(this, SignupActivity::class.java)
                                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
                                intent.putExtra("email", email)
                                startActivity(intent)
                                finish()
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Fail to login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                }    
            }
        }

}
```

Error:

```
2022-01-06 13:20:15.378 12874-12874/com.example.amazontutoringcenter E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.amazontutoringcenter, PID: 12874
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.amazontutoringcenter.LoginActivity.logInToSignUp(LoginActivity.kt:39)
        at com.example.amazontutoringcenter.LoginActivity.onCreate$lambda-0(LoginActivity.kt:31)
        at com.example.amazontutoringcenter.LoginActivity.$r8$lambda$p48sEu5biXL59uzRqdPzRRSVqvg(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.example.amazontutoringcenter.LoginActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onClick(Unknown Source:2)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7281)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7255)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:828)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27925)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:900)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:219)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8393)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1055)
2022-01-06 13:20:15.391 12874-12874/com.example.amazontutoringcenter I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 12874 SIG: 9
```

Comment: When you clear appData and cache, login auth is also cleared hence `auth.currentUser` is also null

Comment: So how to restore it bcak then

Comment: At which particular line of code are you getting that error?

Comment: @Alex Mamo at the line of 39 ( val uid = auth.currentUser!!.uid ).

Comment: Then most likely the user is not authenticated, right?

Comment: The user is authenticated but the user id is  null. As I mentioned it happens after cleaning app data and cahche

Comment: @Phearum if auth is null , ask user to log in again before calling `logInToSignUp`